# BPF filter source address == transmission address

Tags: wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers, tshark, bpf

What is the correct BPF filter for only recieving packets where the source MAC address is equal to the transmission MAC address?

Looking at the documentation, it seems like the fields should be available through either `wlan[21:12]` or `wlan.addr2` but I'm unable to get those to work.

Comment: Are you looking for one particular address that matches or all packets where they match regardless of address?

Comment: All packets where the transmission address is the same as the source address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`pcap-filter` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter), capture filters for tshark or Wireshark **don't support comparing packet fields against each other**.

You can, however, do that with the **display filter** (top bar in Wireshark, once capture started):

```
wlan.sa == wlan.ta
```

---

To check whether the **DS flag is equal to 0x1** using a capture filter, you can do the following:

```
wlan[1] & 3 = 1
```

It retrieves the second byte of the wlan header (`wlan[1]`), masks the 2 lower bits (`& 3`), and compares the result to 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it as a capture filter. After more research, I have found that a DS flag = 0x1 implies that SA == TA.

However, I am still struggling with using the `wlan[2:2] == 0x1` syntax.

Comment: Oh, nice. I didn't know that. I've updated my answer to show how to check the DS flag.

Comment: Great answer! Just make sure you put == for anyone that is copy-pasting.

Comment: "==" shouldn't be necessary.